# How to show Ad Mob add after a certain time user enter into the activity

Tags: java, android, admob

I have put InterstitialAd in a activity. but problem is add appears immediately i enter into the activity. i want that add appears after 20 seconds of user enter to the activity.

Here is My Code:

```
final InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {

                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
                {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }

                else {

                }
            }


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do easily by using below code

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
//Do something after 20s
}
}, 20000);
```